# Cannot get Geolocation with Crosswalk on Ionic Framework (No errors found)

Tags: javascript, cordova, geolocation, ionic-framework, crosswalk-runtime

Before I integrated my Ionic-based application with Crosswalk getting geolocation information is functioning well. But when I used Crosswalk it speeds up my app and functioning well except with the geolocation. I cannot get the latitude/longitude but there is no error alerted in my app.

My code is the same.

```
      var onSuccess = function(position) {
          localStorage.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
          localStorage.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
      };

      function onError(error) {
          alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
      }

      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
```

Answer (score 0):

This feature seems to have been noticed by the crosswalk dev team and has had a bout of fixes so should now be working on most devices. See [this thread](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk/pull/1113) for details.

**The most obvious solution that you must try/verify is that you have enabled location service on your device!**

SETTINGS -> LOCATION -> Enable location (GPS/WIFI)

This is definitely the case for me, however, if you find yourself on an unsupported device (see thread above) then you will have several options...

1. Update your android version.
2. Switch to a compatible device.
3. Wait for crosswalk to support it.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

i've noticed the same. the browser based **navigator.geolocation** object doesn't work from cordova with the crosswalk container for some reason.

you can install the geolocation plugin for cordova.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
```

this solved the problem for me, no code rewriting needed as it replaces the same navigator object.

Answer (score 0):

Using geolocation needs user permission, so you need to specify it on your crosswalk `manifest.json` by adding something like:

```
"xwalk_permissions": [
  "Contacts",
  "Geolocation",
  "Messaging",
  "Vibration"
 ]
```

(read https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/manifest/permissions.html).

#### UPDATE

I solved with:

```
  "xwalk_android_permissions": [ "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" ]
```